# Access union elements directly in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, unions

With IAR compiler it is possible to define anonymous union like this:

```
  typedef struct
  {
    unsigned char no0:1;
    unsigned char no1:1;
    unsigned char no2:1;
    unsigned char no3:1;
    unsigned char no4:1;
    unsigned char no5:1;
    unsigned char no6:1;
    unsigned char no7:1;
  } __BITS8;

__saddr __no_init volatile union
{
  unsigned char P0;
  __BITS8       P0_bit;
} @ 0xFFF00;
```

And it is possible to access P0 or P0_bit directly:

```
P0 = 0x80;
```

Which changes the other variable due to them having the same address:

```
P0_bit.no7 == 1 // returns true
```

My question is, if is possible something like this with GCC, but without absolute addressing. Basically I just need to have two variables P0 and P0_bit share the same address.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for can be achieved like this:

```
union {
    struct {
        unsigned char bitone:1;
        unsigned char bittwo:1;
        unsigned char bitthree:1;
        unsigned char bitfour:1;
        unsigned char bitfive:1;
        unsigned char bitsix:1;
        unsigned char bitseven:1;
        unsigned char biteight:1;
    } bits;
    unsigned char byte;
}
```

Here the series of bits and the byte are in a union, so they still occupy the same memory. Note that this example doesn't use any `typedef`'ing or define any structure or union type names. You can still do that if you'd like.

P.S. You shouldn't use `__BITS8` as a name in your `typedef`; that's a reserved identifier.

Comment: `unsigned char bitone:1;`?  [You sure about where that bit is?](http://www.port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p11)  "An implementation may allocate **any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field**. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, **whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined**.  ...

Comment: (cont) "...The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is **implementation-defined**. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified."  Relying on the location of a bit when using bit-fields, especially when multiple implementations are relevant, is not a good idea.

Comment: First of all `__BITS8` typedef is from IAR not from my headers. Second, your answer is unrelated to my problem. I need directly access union members as I mentioned in my question `P0 = 0x80;` and you just declared ordinary anonymous union with nested anonymous struct.